# How do I make sure the touchpad is enabled on reboot?

Tags: boot, scripts, login, touchpad

Just installed Ubuntu Mate, and am facing a strange issue: *I have to manually enable the trackpad every-time I reboot the system..*

It's getting quite annoying, and if anyone can help out by creating a script or something or point me to a program, or help out in simulating the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and the <kbd>F7</kbd> key, that would be awesome..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to simulate the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key through using like `xdotool` or something similar.  However, that being said, you can write a script that you can run at startup to enable your trackpad.

*This is an alternate way to do this.*

For this, we are going to use `xinput`.  Unfortunately, I do not have a trackpad on this system, but the commands should be used the same way.

First, run from a terminal the following command:

```
xinput --list
```

you are going to be looking for your trackpad in the list.  *I am just going to use my mouse as the example.*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xinput --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Kensington      USB/PS2 Wheel Mouse       id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

My mouse is shown as `Kensington      USB/PS2 Wheel Mouse` so that is what we are going to get the `props` for.  Run the next command to see the `props` that you can set for the device:

```
xinput --list-props '<device name>'
```

*Example: (Mine gives a ton of information, so I truncated it to the information we need.  Device Enabled is really what we are looking for.)*

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ xinput --list-props 'Kensington      USB/PS2 Wheel Mouse'
Device 'Kensington      USB/PS2 Wheel Mouse':
    Device Enabled (152):   1
```

The `Device Enabled (152): 1` shows that my mouse is enabled.  To disable my mouse it would be just to set that to `0`, but in your case you want it enabled or set to `1`.  The command to enable it would be:

```
xinput --set-prop '<device name>' 'Device Enabled' 1
```

My command to enable my mouse would be:

```
xinput --set-prop 'Kensington      USB/PS2 Wheel Mouse' 'Device Enabled' 1
```

Then you can add the command with the full path to the `xinput` command to the `/etc/rc.local` file.  You need to make sure that you keep the `exit 0` as the last line in the `/etc/rc.local` file.

```
which xinput
```

will give you the full path to the file.

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ which xinput
/usr/bin/xinput
```

After you have that, now add your line to the `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
/usr/bin/xinput --set-prop '<device name>' 'Device Enabled' 1
```

That should now run before you get to the login screen.

It has been brought to my attention that it can get overruled after login.  So, you can add a `.desktop` file to the `/etc/xdg/autostart/` folder that will launch with every user that logs into the system.

I called my file `mouse_enable.desktop` and I added the following lines to it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=mouse_enable
Exec=/bin/bash -c 'sleep 15 && /usr/bin/xinput --set-prop "<device name>" "Device Enabled" 1'
```

Make the file owned by root:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/xdg/autostart/mouse_enable.desktop
```

Make the file have the correct permissions:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/xdg/autostart/mouse_enable.desktop
```

Now when logging in it should keep the device enabled.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If it works, it will most likely be overruled on login.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Yep, that does do it.  I updated my answer to have a global desktop file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Added.  Mine it was fine on not having it as I tested for disabling the mouse, but I get what you're saying.  Best to be safe than sorry.  I also updated to show that my answer is an alternate way of doing this.  =)

Comment: Cool, should cover all issues :)